# Reactjs: TypeError: this.authHandler is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my method

```
authHandler(authData){

    if(!this.isMounted())
        return;

    const storeRef = myDatabase.ref(this.props.storeId);

    storeRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val() || {};

        if(!data.owner){
            storeRef.set({
                owner: authData.user.uid
            });
        }

        this.setState({
            uid: authData.user.uid,
            owner: data.owner || authData.user.uid
        });

        // localStorage.setItem(`authData-${this.props.storeId}`, JSON.stringify(authData));
    });
}
```

and here is the componentDidMount()

```
   componentDidMount(){

    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user, error){
        if(!error && this.handleErrors){
            this.handleErrors(error);
            return;
        }

        if(user){
            console.log(user);
            this.authHandler(user);
        }
    });
}
```

But no matter what I do, it always throws:

> TypeError: this.authHandler is not a function

I read through some similar questions: e.g.
[ReactJS - this.functionname is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740875/reactjs-this-functionname-is-not-a-function)

but none of them work for me.

Comment: Use an arrow function for the event handler.

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks, this works for me can you please explain the reason? thanks

Comment: See the link. TLDR regular function expressions have their `this` set by how they're called. Usually, `this` will refer to `window` inside a regular function expression in a callback because of how they're called. Arrow functions do not bind their own `this`. The `this` value inside an arrow function refers to the `this` from the enclosing scope. Thus `this` inside an arrow function will refer to the component, not `window`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use arrow function:

```
 componentDidMount(){

    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user, error) => {
        if(!error && this.handleErrors){
            this.handleErrors(error);
            return;
        }

        if(user){
            console.log(user);
            this.authHandler(user);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander,  it works for me :)  But can you please explain the reason? thanks

Comment: Arrows functions have "lexical scoping" instead of "dynamical" so you will get your class as "this" instead of other class or function. You can read here about it https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/

Comment: beautiful, thanks~!